# Find Clusters in a Multidimensional Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to find the number of clusters given a multidimensional Array of 0's and 1's. A cluster is defined by 1's that are adjacent in either up, down, left or right directions **NOT diagonal**. Meaning the following multidimensional array has one cluster:

```
01000
01000
```

AND the next one has two:

```
00100
00010
```

I have written code (See MY CODE below) but upon compiling and testing with a couple of use cases it is failing to provide the consistent accurate answer:

When the following is run it should produce the following results:

RUN:

```
package org.example;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        FindCluster findCluster = new FindCluster();
        FindCluster findCluster0 = new FindCluster();
        FindCluster findCluster1 = new FindCluster();
        FindCluster findCluster2 = new FindCluster();
        // Attempt 1

        int myArr[][] = {
                {1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}
        };

        int numOfClusters = findCluster.findNumberOfClusters(5, 5, myArr);
        System.out.println("The number of clusters found in your Array is: " + numOfClusters);

        // Attempt 2

        int myArr0[][] = {
                {1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                {0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                {0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}
        };

        int numOfClusters0 = findCluster0.findNumberOfClusters(5, 5, myArr0);
        System.out.println("The number of clusters found in your Array is: " + numOfClusters0);

        // Attempt 3

        int myArr1[][] = {
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                {0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}
        };

        int numOfClusters1 = findCluster1.findNumberOfClusters(5, 5, myArr1);
        System.out.println("The number of clusters found in your Array is: " + numOfClusters1);

        // Attempt 4

        int myArr2[][] = {
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                {0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}
        };

        int numOfClusters2 = findCluster2.findNumberOfClusters(5, 5, myArr2);
        System.out.println("The number of clusters found in your Array is: " + numOfClusters2);
    }
}
```

Expected Results:

```
The number of clusters found in your Array is: 5
The number of clusters found in your Array is: 7
The number of clusters found in your Array is: 4
The number of clusters found in your Array is: 3
```

Actual Results:

```
The number of clusters found in your Array is: 5
The number of clusters found in your Array is: 6
The number of clusters found in your Array is: 3
The number of clusters found in your Array is: 4
```

MY CODE:

```
package org.example;

public class FindCluster {

    private int clusters = 0;

    private boolean gridCheckArr[][] = null;

    private int gridClusterArr[][] = null;

    public void setGridCheckArr(int rows, int columns) {
        this.gridCheckArr = new boolean[rows][columns];
    }

    public void setGridClusterArr(int gridClusterArr[][]) { this.gridClusterArr = gridClusterArr; }

    public void setGridCheckInitialValues(){
        for(int r = 0;r < gridCheckArr.length; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < gridCheckArr[r].length; c++){
                gridCheckArr[r][c] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public Integer findNumberOfClusters(int rows, int columns, int grid[][]) {

        // Using a method to set a grid to check if location has been visited
        setGridCheckArr(rows, columns);
        // Using a method to set the initial values to false for the grid being checked
        setGridCheckInitialValues();
        // Using a method to set the the classes grid to the grid passed to the method called
        setGridClusterArr(grid);
        // Using a method that performs the checks and computation of the clusters
        gridCheck();

        return this.clusters;
    }

    public void gridCheck() {
        for(int r = 0; r < gridCheckArr.length; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < gridCheckArr[r].length; c++) {
                if(r == 0 && c == 0){
                    checkFirstRowBeginning(r, c);
                } else if (r == 0 && c == gridCheckArr[r].length - 1) {
                    checkFirstRowEnd(r, c);
                } else if ( r == 0 && c > 0) {
                    checkFirstRow(r, c);
                } else if (r == gridCheckArr.length - 1 && c == 0) {
                    checkLastRowBeginning(r, c);
                } else if (r == gridCheckArr.length -1 && c == gridCheckArr[r].length -1) {
                    checkLastRowEnd(r, c);
                } else if (r == gridCheckArr.length -1 && c > 0) {
                    checkLastRow(r, c);
                } else if (r > 0 && c == 0) {
                    checkRowBeginning(r, c);
                } else if (r > 0 && c == gridCheckArr[r].length -1) {
                    checkRowEnd(r, c);
                } else if (r > 0 && c > 0) {
                    checkRow(r, c);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Oops something went wrong trying to find a grid check!!!!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkFirstRow(int row, int column) { // checks Left, Right, Down
        int arrIndexValue = this.gridClusterArr[row][column];
        switch(arrIndexValue) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                this.gridCheckArr[row][column] = true;
                if(this.gridCheckArr[row][column - 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row][column + 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row + 1][column] != true) {
                    this.clusters++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Oops something went wrong when trying to check grid at First Row case not able to be handled array index value is: " + arrIndexValue);
        }
    }

    public void checkFirstRowBeginning(int row, int column) { // checks Right, Down
        int arrIndexValue = this.gridClusterArr[row][column];
        switch(arrIndexValue) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                this.gridCheckArr[row][column] = true;
                if(this.gridCheckArr[row][column + 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row + 1][column] != true) {
                    this.clusters++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Oops something went wrong when trying to check grid at First Row Beginning case not able to be handled array index value is: " + arrIndexValue);
        }
    }

    public void checkFirstRowEnd(int row, int column) { // checks Left, Down
        int arrIndexValue = this.gridClusterArr[row][column];
        switch(arrIndexValue) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                this.gridCheckArr[row][column] = true;
                if(this.gridCheckArr[row][column - 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row + 1][column] != true) {
                    this.clusters++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Oops something went wrong when trying to check grid at First Row End case not able to be handled array index value is: " + arrIndexValue);
        }
    }

    public void checkRow(int row, int column) { // checks Left, Right, Up, Down
        int arrIndexValue = this.gridClusterArr[row][column];
        switch(arrIndexValue) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                this.gridCheckArr[row][column] = true;
                if(this.gridCheckArr[row][column - 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row][column + 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row - 1][column] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row + 1][column] != true) {
                    if((this.gridCheckArr[row - 1][column - 1] != true && this.gridClusterArr[row][column - 1] != 1) && (this.gridCheckArr[row - 1][column + 1] != true && this.gridClusterArr[row][column + 1] != 1) && (this.gridCheckArr[row + 1][column - 1] != true && this.gridClusterArr[row][column - 1] != 1) && (this.gridCheckArr[row + 1][column + 1] != true && this.gridClusterArr[row][column + 1] != 1)) {
                        this.clusters++;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Oops something went wrong when trying to check grid at a Row case not able to be handled array index value is: " + arrIndexValue);
        }
    }

    public void checkRowBeginning(int row, int column) { // checks Right, Up, Down
        int arrIndexValue = this.gridClusterArr[row][column];
        switch(arrIndexValue) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                this.gridCheckArr[row][column] = true;
                if(this.gridCheckArr[row][column + 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row - 1][column] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row + 1][column] != true) {
                    this.clusters++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Oops something went wrong when trying to check grid at a Row Beginning case not able to be handled array index value is: " + arrIndexValue);
        }
    }

    public void checkRowEnd(int row, int column) { // checks Left, Up, Down
        int arrIndexValue = this.gridClusterArr[row][column];
        switch(arrIndexValue) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                this.gridCheckArr[row][column] = true;
                if(this.gridCheckArr[row][column - 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row - 1][column] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row + 1][column] != true) {
                    this.clusters++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Oops something went wrong when trying to check grid at a Row End case not able to be handled array index value is: " + arrIndexValue);
        }
    }

    public void checkLastRow(int row, int column) { // checks Left, Right, Up
        int arrIndexValue = this.gridClusterArr[row][column];
        switch(arrIndexValue) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                this.gridCheckArr[row][column] = true;
                if(this.gridCheckArr[row][column - 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row][column + 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row - 1][column] != true) {
                    this.clusters++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Oops something went wrong when trying to check grid at Last Row case not able to be handled array index value is: " + arrIndexValue);
        }
    }

    public void checkLastRowBeginning(int row, int column) { // checks Right, Up
        int arrIndexValue = this.gridClusterArr[row][column];
        switch(arrIndexValue) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                this.gridCheckArr[row][column] = true;
                if(this.gridCheckArr[row][column + 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row - 1][column] != true) {
                    this.clusters++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Oops something went wrong when trying to check grid at Last Row Beginning case not able to be handled array index value is: " + arrIndexValue);
        }
    }

    public void checkLastRowEnd(int row, int column) { // checks  Left, Up
        int arrIndexValue = this.gridClusterArr[row][column];
        switch(arrIndexValue) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                this.gridCheckArr[row][column] = true;
                if(this.gridCheckArr[row][column - 1] != true && this.gridCheckArr[row - 1][column] != true) {
                    this.clusters++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Oops something went wrong when trying to check grid at Last Row End case not able to be handled array index value is: " + arrIndexValue);
        }

    }
}
```

I see why it is failing when I hand trace it logically in certain scenarios. However, I'm getting stuck on finding an algorithm that will address the issue. For example, in Attempt 4 for myArr2

```
int myArr2[][] = {
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                {0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}
        };
```

The clusters count is first incremented from **0** to **1** on the first **1** identified on the first column (index of [0][0]). Then when it gets to the third **1** identified on the first column (index of [0][3]) my logical check increments the clusters count by **1** again. This is incorrect as it is actually connected in a cluster to the first two **1's** identified previously in the first row (indexes [0][0] and [0][1]) as defined if you follow the adjacent **1's** in the entire two dimensional array. How to create an logical algorithm to realize this?

Anyone who can improve my code to fix the bugs or provide a better/more efficient solution with an explanation of how/why it works better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To find number of clusters, you will have to move in all 4 directions recursively, adopting a [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) approach whenever you find a cell with value 1.
- The way DFS works is it marks all cells that are connected 4 directionally in one shot. So, we get a cluster. We don't visit the same cell while searching for other clusters as we mark these cells as visited.
- In order to mark a cell as visited, we will modify it's value to -1 and later restore it back to 1 making it space efficient.

**Snippet:**

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myArr[][] = {
                {1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}
        };


        System.out.println(findNumClusters(myArr));
    }

    private static int findNumClusters(int[][] arr){
        int num_clusters = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<arr.length;++j){
                if(arr[i][j] == 1){
                    dfs(arr,i,j,arr.length,arr[0].length);
                    num_clusters++;
                }
            }
        }

        // restore all ones
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<arr.length;++j){
                if(arr[i][j] == -1) arr[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }

        return num_clusters;
    }

    private static void dfs(int[][] arr,int x,int y,int rows,int cols){
        if(x < 0 || x == rows || y < 0 || y == cols || arr[x][y] != 1) return;
        arr[x][y] = -1; // marking a cell as visited(will be restored later)
        dfs(arr,x-1,y,rows,cols);
        dfs(arr,x+1,y,rows,cols);
        dfs(arr,x,y-1,rows,cols);
        dfs(arr,x,y+1,rows,cols);
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://www.onlinegdb.com/HJLJR56eU

Comment: Thanks you for the contribution @vivek_23 this is amazingly innovative and appears to be withstanding the trials. The logic looks like it makes sense as I trace it. Correct me if i'm wrong, but it looks like you actually follow all possible connected paths and mark them -1 so that any of the indexes will not be revisited again in the for loop that checks each index of the array?

Comment: For my understanding this means if the conditions of the if statement in the dfs method are NOT met the first time it finds a 1 and calls  it. Then it will execute each additional line of code in the method resulting in it calling itself recursively until no 1's are found. Additionally, each time a line of code within the dfs method calls the method again it returns back to the line that called the dfs method is this correct?

Comment: For example, dfs(arr,x-1,y,rows,cols) calls the dfs method which will then either return back if conditional statement is met and execute dfs(arr,x+1,y,rows,cols) etc. OR it will start the process of executing  dfs(arr,x-1,y,rows,cols) again each time incrementing the indexes resulting in new location checks until all connected 1's of the particular cluster is changed to -1. Is that accurate? Sorry for the multiple comments/questions as my user name suggest I don't just want to get an answer I want to expand my understanding in the process. Thank!

Comment: @alwaySearchingForSolutions _dfs(arr,x-1,y,rows,cols) calls the dfs method which will then either return back if conditional statement is met and execute dfs(arr,x+1,y,rows,cols) etc_ This is correct. If `if` condition is not met, then it will go new locations recursively. You got everything absolutely correct. I am glad my code is readable. Cheers :)